# Can I query an S3 Inventory for all files matching a prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I may not have asked the right question.  I'm trying to use boto3 to copy all files matching a given prefix from one bucket to another.  The number of files could be quite large, so I thought using the inventory feature to create a batch job manifest would be the way to go but I'm finding the documentation... lacking.  I can't see any way to get a list of file names from an inventory based on a prefix--it seems to be all or nothing.  Am I misunderstanding batch jobs and inventories?

Comment: Inventory is just a csv file, so what is the problem with parsing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 Inventory provides a CSV file.

You can parse the CSV file within your Python code to apply any type of string filtering you wish.

Comment: Got it--I misunderstood the requirements of the manifest for a batch job.  Thanks!